# Limit of series of function, uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $, $ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 2^{n-1} \sin \frac{x}{2^{n-1}} \sin^2 \frac{x}{2^n} \right)$

What is the limit of $ f(x)g(x) $ at $ x\to 0 $?

Can I exchange lim and sigma to reach the following conclusion?

$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = 0$

I don't think g(x) is uniformly convergent but it seems so at around $ x = 0 $, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$h(x)=f(x)g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{x} \sin \frac{x}{2^{n-1}} \sin^2 \frac{x}{2^n}$$

We have $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$. Estimating the summand in the definition of $g$ accordingly gives

$$\left|\frac{2^{n-1}}{x}\sin \frac{x}{2^{n-1}} \sin^2 \frac{x}{2^n}\right|\le \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

Therefore, the series for $h$ converges uniformly in $|x|<4$ (Weierstrass $M$-test). Note that the same estimate shows that the series for $g$ *is* uniformly convergent around $0$, answering your last question.
In particular, we can interchange limit and sum to get

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} h(x)=0$$

Comment: Definitely h(x) is not uniformly convergent for all real number?

Comment: @AllenJung: Yes, definitely not.